# Is there a way to activate a node file on button click on a website

Tags: onclick

Let me start by saying I am an absolute newbie when it comes to node, or doing anything with api. But I was wondering if it is possible for me to click a button on a website, and then this runs a js file on my computer which goes to a twillio account and sends a message to myself. Like I said no idea if this is possible just curious thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers don't allow this, because it would make it way too easy to hack into people's laptops.